# Switching between QFileSystemModel filters

Tags: python, pyqt5

The contents of QFileSystemModel are displayed in a QTreeView, and I want to switch between listing folders only and files only in the current directory. It is first initialized with a filter for folders `model.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)`. Then, when setting the filter for files `QDir.Files | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot`, the first folder that was displayed before is still shown. I figured it had to do with the first item being the view's `currentIndex`, so adding `view.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())` does fix that. However, if a folder is selected and then the filter is switched for displaying files only, that folder will still be shown, even when calling `view.clearSelection()` right before. (And I would like to keep the selection mode on `SingleSelection`).

I was wondering if QFileSystemModel was not intended to be used that way, and `setFilter` should only be used once, or if there is a solution. If I create a new model every time I want to change the filter then it does work properly, but I can't imagine that's the best usage either.

Ultimately, I'll be using a proxy model for other custom filtering. Trying this with a default QSortFilterProxyModel does not update the contents at all when the filter is changed, it only shows the folders. If I include `QDir.AllDirs` in the filter, as instructed in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter), it does seem to update the contents correctly. But that option will include folders and files together, when I just want to show files.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Model(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)
        model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.view = QTreeView(uniformRowHeights=True, itemsExpandable=False, rootIsDecorated=False)
        self.view.setModel(model)
        self.view.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath()))
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QRadioButton('Folders', checked=True), 1, 0, Qt.AlignRight)
        grid.addWidget(QRadioButton('Files', toggled=self.changefilter), 1, 1)

    def changefilter(self, checked):
        self.view.clearSelection()
        self.view.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())
        model = self.view.model()
        if checked:
            model.setFilter(QDir.Files | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)# | QDir.AllDirs)
        else:
            model.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)


class ModelWithProxy(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)
        model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self.view = QTreeView(uniformRowHeights=True, itemsExpandable=False, rootIsDecorated=False)
        self.view.setModel(proxy)
        self.view.setRootIndex(proxy.mapFromSource(model.index(QDir.currentPath())))
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.view, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(QRadioButton('Folders', checked=True), 1, 0, Qt.AlignRight)
        grid.addWidget(QRadioButton('Files', toggled=self.changefilter), 1, 1)

    def changefilter(self, checked):
        self.view.clearSelection()
        self.view.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())
        proxy = self.view.model()
        model = proxy.sourceModel()
        if checked:
            model.setFilter(QDir.Files | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)# | QDir.AllDirs)
        else:
            model.setFilter(QDir.Dirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QDir.AllDirs)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    hbox = QHBoxLayout(window)
    hbox.addWidget(Model())
    hbox.addWidget(ModelWithProxy())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I reproduced this behavior with several versions up to PyQt5 5.15 on both Windows and macOS.

Comment: It seems like a bug, probably caused by the caching system used by QFileSystemModel (even if it's quite strange that it keeps track of the "last selected" item). After a simple research, it doesn't seem that there is any actual report about it, so you should consider submitting one.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your insight. Perhaps the best approach then is to replicate the filter in a `QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow()` reimplement.